# Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

When I'm running this query on my page, I'm getting a

> Subqueries are not allowed in this
>   context. Only scalar expressions are
>   allowed

error. What am I doing wrong?

```
insert into Konular(KonuAd, AltKategoriID, KategoriID, KonuSahibi,GönderenID, İçerik,KonuTarih,SonMesajTarihi) 
values(@Başlık,'184','0',@KonuSahibi,'27',@İçerik,'04.09.2010 08:35:19',(select convert(datetime,'04.09.2010 08:35:19',104)))
```

Comment: I ran into this issue when running SQL Server 2005 (v. 9), these sort of queries do work on SQL Server 2008+ (v. 10+)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a subquery in a context where only scalar expressions are allowed :-)

You don't need the `select`.  Try:

```
insert into Konular(KonuAd, AltKategoriID, KategoriID, KonuSahibi,GönderenID, İçerik,KonuTarih,SonMesajTarihi) 
values(@Başlık,'184','0',@KonuSahibi,'27',@İçerik,'04.09.2010 08:35:19', convert(datetime,'04.09.2010 08:35:19',104))
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove (select ), because its a subquery and its not allowed.

```
values(@Başlık,'184','0',@KonuSahibi,'27',@İçerik,'04.09.2010 08:35:19', cast( '04.09.2010 08:35:19' AS datetime )
```